# Powershell send variable as Read-Host input

Tags: powershell

I have the following function

```
   function someFunc {
    $something1 = Read-Host
    $something2 = Read-Host
    echo $something1 $something2
    }
```

How can I call this function with passing two strings avoiding writing to console (avoiding Read-Host)?

I don't want change function someFunc!

What i really need to do is to automate some script which asks 2 times for password

like i would like to have followings commands from this

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/en-gb/cross-industry/2016/06/08/setting-up-active-directory-via-powershell/

in script.
But last step of this require to pass the password to the console 2 times

Comment: What about using the `param()` block? Then you can write `someFunc -thing1 ****** -thing2 *****`

Comment: You could look those specific cmdlets up. Most of them will have a `-Credential`, `-ADPrepCredential` or `-SafeModeAdministratorPassword` etc. parameter. You then just need to get your credentials once with `$creds = Get-Credential`. After that you can pass them to every cmdlet to the proper parameters.

Comment: i have found that i can pass this password to install adforest with SafeModeAdministratorPassword